# Not adding HTML package to Laravel using composer

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel provides various in built tags to handle HTML forms easily and securely. All the major elements of HTML are generated using Laravel. So i am going to take this facility but its not working.

> I use **composer require laravelcollective/html**.

**Command prompt says:**

```
laravel>composer require laravelcollective/html
Using version ^5.2 for laravelcollective/html
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

> Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use
>   laravelcollective/html instead.

```
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
```

Comment: Isn't that package already added as the illuminate/html package as a dependency of the framework?

Comment: @Tacsiazuma, did't get you, but first time i tried with **composer require illuminate/html**

Comment: What's in the composer.json, or can you find anything related that html package inside the composer.lock file, or inside the vendor folder?

Comment: I am new with laravel, so i did't any check. What to do??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for a `vendor/illuminate/html` or `vendor/laravelcollective/html` folder, relative to the project root. 
Look for the `illuminate/html` or `laravelcollective/html` string inside the `composer.json` or `composer.lock`.

The first one is the dependencies you defined, the seconde file contains the already installed ones.

I guess you already have that package as composer said nothing to install or update.

If the composer.lock or the vendor folder contains any of the strings/folders, then you have already installed it and can use them in your code.

**UPDATE**

Register the service provider in `config/app.php` by adding the following value into the providers array:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class
```

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

```
 'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: Yes i found them and remove the illuminate one and make a try again now its fine. But the form not working for what i do these things...

**Class 'Form' not found** when i execute the form with form handle..

Comment: I use _echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar'));_ in my form.

Comment: After adding these to app.php, i got another error. **Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found**.

Comment: Look for the folders inside the vendor folder. Is there an illuminate/html one?

Comment: Nope... No folder like that name

Comment: But there was the folder named **illuminate** before i execute **composer require laravelcollective/html**.

Comment: The composer.lock file contains an entry with either illuminate/html or laravelcollective/html?

If the second one is present, check the corresponding folder in the vendor. And look for a HtmlServiceProvider or any ServiceProvider class, and use it instead inside your config/app.php

Comment: I found HTMLServiceProvider at **vendor\laravelcollective\html\src**, and added this path to app.php like **laravelcollective\html\src\HtmlServiceProvider::class,** but still not found message.

Comment: You are helping me a lot and what is my problem almost done. Better i accept your answer and discuss a little more.

Comment: use the namespace definition (sg like 'LaravelCollective\Html') found inside the top of the file instead of the full relative path to prefix it, as it's mapped by it with the composer's autoloader.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116970/discussion-between-tacsiazuma-and-frayne-konok).